# Symfony Omines Datatables column option 'filter'

Tags: symfony, datatable, datatables

Good afternoon, could you add an example column with the 'filter' option to the documentation, or give an example here.I will be very grateful to you

Comment: I would too. I can't figure out how i can have a filter cell on each column. In the code, i can see it waits some column.filter.templateHTML and placeholder parameters but what is to be in these ?

Comment: @Jice I studied this question more, and realized that this functionality has not yet been fully implemented, a solution lies in one of the branches, but so far it is at the merger stage [link](https://github.com/omines/datatables-bundle/pull/150)